# LEFT JOIN | ORDER BY query speed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in my website that is creating a speed bottleneck. An experienced PHP/MySql developer looked at the query and immediately saw the problem, explained a bit about how it should be optimally structured, and then (as happens with so many web developers, sadly) promptly vanished.

Here is the problematic query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.title, a.thumb_image 
FROM artwork a 
LEFT JOIN galleries_artwork ga 
ON a.id = ga.artwork_id 
WHERE ga.galleries_id = $gallery_id 
ORDER BY ga.position
```

He had said the query was sorting the result set in a way that takes 3x longer than it would if it were rewritten to put at the beginning [...and here's where I can't remember exactly what he explained].

Can anyone see what's wrong with this from a speed-optimization standpoint, and explain it and what would optimize it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `distinct` is a major problem.  Also, you are turning the `left join` into an `inner join` because of the `where` clause, so this may be what you want:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.thumb_image 
FROM artwork a JOIN
     galleries_artwork ga 
     ON a.id = ga.artwork_id 
WHERE ga.galleries_id = $gallery_id 
ORDER BY ga.position
```

Indexes on `galleries_artwork(galleryies_id, position, artwork_id)` and `artwork(id, title, thumb_image)` would be optimal for this version of the query.

Comment: Your proposed revision does in fact speed it up tremendously; the MIA developer had discussed something about putting elements of the query in parentheses, as you suggest further. But would that mean this:

    SELECT a.id, a.title, a.thumb_image 
    FROM artwork(id, title, thumb_image) a JOIN
        galleries_artwork(galleries_id, position, artwork_id) ga
        ON a.id = ga.artwork_id 
    WHERE ga.galleries_id = $gallery_id 
    ORDER BY ga.position

?

Comment: @Tom . . . I do not think that would have any effect on performance.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon...I had misunderstood the second part of your suggestion. I checked the database and not all of the columns you listed had been indexed; I indexed them, and now the search should work as you suggested.